# How i can tell reportportal that next skip/failed item should have custom defect, instead of To_Investigate

Tags: reportportal

During tests we have many results related to System Issues. How i can move result into my custom defect type "No Data" instead "To investigate"

How i can tell reportportal that next skip related to NoData. Auto Analyze doesn't work with skipped test

[System Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QdQg.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I guess, this question should has label *How i can tell reportportal that next skip/failed item should have custom defect, instead of To_Investigate*

By default all fails considered by **ReportPortal** as `To Investigate`.
Basically, if failed item received by RP - defect object with defect_type="TO_INVESTIGATE" will be assigned.

as an example, if you use `TestNG` you can add `rp.skipped.issue = false` attribute.

```
rp.skipped.issue = option to mark skipped tests as not 'To Investigate' items on Server side. Boolean values: TRUE - skipped tests considered as issues and will be mark as 'To Investigate'. FALSE - skipped tests will not be mark as 'To Investigate' on portal.
```

Also API support submitting of custom defect right with failed/skipped item.

So you just need to extend your framework agent, and let him send specific defect type for skips or fails.

[image]

Comment: Dzmitry, could you give me more details?

Answer (score 0):

Please see implementation in `client-java`

In few words: you should send issue `type` with name `NOT_ISSUE` in case if you don't need `To Investigate` flag for skipped/any testItem.
https://github.com/reportportal/client-java/commit/36c1624da17694fc2355ab0f628b2f1cc8a35c96#diff-69c3ef7f422402a9c55c68c001df11d1a06d0bd0c1df2d4e2e59406b50c91e2bR317

https://github.com/reportportal/client-java/commit/36c1624da17694fc2355ab0f628b2f1cc8a35c96